# Collection::addAttributeToSelect() undefined method in Magento

Tags: magento

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Desbest_Showdown_Model_Mysql4_Votes_Collection::addAttributeToSelect()
>   in
>   /home/desbest/public_html/clients/magentofull/app/code/local/Desbest/Showdown/controllers/IndexController.php
>   on line 19

**IndexController.php**

```
public function voteAction(){
    $shake = Mage::getModel('showdown/votes')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ;
}
```

===============

> code/local/Desbest/Showdown/Model/Mysql4/Votes/**Collection.php**

```
<?php
class Desbest_Showdown_Model_Mysql4_Votes_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('showdown/votes');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`addAttributeToSelect()` is using for `EAV` style model collection only (product, customer, etc.)

For other models you can use `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract::addFieldToSelect()` method.

Comment: All I had to do is change `addAttributeToSelect` to `addFieldToFilter` and `addAttributeToFilter` to `addFieldToFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Collection.php

```
public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir=’asc’) 
{ 
    if (!is_string($attribute)) { 
        return $this; 
    } 
    $this->setOrder($attribute, $dir); 
    return $this; 
}
```

You could also try using addFilter() or using setOrder().

Resource: [This](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/51116/)

Comment: But I want the `addAttributeToSelect` function.